# Is this number Liouville?

Tags: irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, liouville-numbers

If $b\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant2}$, is the number given by the following sum:

$M=\displaystyle\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geqslant0}}b^{-10^{n}}$

a Liouville number?

It has lots of zeros, for sure, and by examining the continued fraction for $M$ when $b=10$ has lots of large terms consisting of all nines. For example ($9_a$ denotes a number consisting of $a$ nines):

$\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}10^{-10^{n}}=\left[0~|~9,1,9_8,10,9_{80},1,9,9_8,1,9,9_{800},1,8,1,9_8,9,1,9_{80},10,9_8,1,9,9_{8000},\ldots\right]$

This continued fraction exhibits the same "mirroring" effect as Liouville's Constant where the terms after the next incrementally largest term that consists of all nines, $a_n$, are the same as the non-zero terms before it, except that the preceding term $a_{n-1}$ is replaced by a $1$ followed by $a_{n-1}-1$.

Answer (score 3):

The definition of a 
Liouville number
is
"a real number x with the property that, for every positive integer n, there exist integers p and q with q > 1 and such that
$0 < \left| x-\dfrac{p}{q}
\right| < \dfrac1{q^n}
$
or
$q^n < \dfrac1{\left| x-\dfrac{p}{q}
\right|}
$.

In your case,

$\left| x-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\dfrac1{b^{10^{k}}}\right|
\approx \dfrac1{b^{10^{n}}}
$.

Here,
$q = b^{10^{n-1}}
$
so you want
$(b^{10^{n-1}})^n
\lt b^{10^{n}}
$
or
$b^{n10^{n-1}}
\lt b^{10^{n}}
$
which is not true for
$n > 10
$.

Therefore your number is
*not* a
Liouville number.

That is why using $n!$ instead of
$10^n$ works -
try it.

Comment: Thanks, and now I'm seeing it. The number of zeros increases exponentially in this constant, whereas in Liouville's Constant the number of zeros increases much faster (since factorials increase faster than exponentials).

Comment: I agree, you can't use the partial sums as your approximating rationals, so the "easy" proof won't work, but does that mean you can't use some *other* sequence of rationals as close approximants?

Comment: What others would there be? Would getting the continued fraction for this number do any better?